# Sum of values from related rows in Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame where some rows have one ID and one related ID. In the example below, `a1` and `a2` are related (say to the same person) while `b` and `c` don't have any related rows.

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame(
    [['a1', 1, 'a2'],
     ['a1', 2, 'a2'],
     ['a1', 3, 'a2'],
     ['a2', 4, 'a1'],
     ['a2', 5, 'a1'],
     ['b',  6,     ],
     ['c',  7,     ]],
    columns=['ID1', 'Value', 'ID2']
)

test
  ID1  Value   ID2
0  a1      1    a2
1  a1      2    a2
2  a1      3    a2
3  a2      4    a1
4  a2      5    a1
5   b      6  None
6   c      7  None
```

What I need to achieve is to add a column containing the sum of all values for related rows. In this case, the desired output should be like below. Is there a way to get this, please?

| ID1 | Value | ID2 | Group by ID1 and ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1 | a2 | 15 |
| a1 | 2 | a2 | 15 |
| a1 | 3 | a2 | 15 |
| a2 | 4 | a1 | 15 |
| a2 | 5 | a1 | 15 |
| b | 6 |  | 6 |
| c | 7 |  | 7 |

Note that I learnt to use `group by` to get sum for `ID1` (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74956866/value-not-updated-in-for-loop-python/74957091#74957091)); but not for 'ID1' and 'ID2' together.

```
test['Group by ID1'] = test.groupby("ID1")["Value"].transform("sum")
test

  ID1  Value   ID2  Group by ID1
0  a1      1    a2             6
1  a1      2    a2             6
2  a1      3    a2             6
3  a2      4    a1             9
4  a2      5    a1             9
5   b      6  None             6
6   c      7  None             7
```

**Update**

Think I can still use `for` loop to get this done like below. But wondering if there is another non-loop way. Thanks.

```
bottle = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(test)
bottle['ID1'] = test['ID1']
bottle['ID2'] = test['ID2']

for index, row in bottle.iterrows():
    bottle.loc[index, "Value"] = test[test['ID1'] == row['ID1']]['Value'].sum() + \
    test[test['ID1'] == row['ID2']]['Value'].sum()

print(bottle)

  ID1  Value   ID2
0  a1   15.0    a2
1  a1   15.0    a2
2  a1   15.0    a2
3  a2   15.0    a1
4  a2   15.0    a1
5   b    6.0  None
6   c    7.0  None
```

Comment: Please do not put what is not code in the same code block as what is code.

Comment: @starball Hope this works. Let me know otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution would be to sort the pairs in `ID1` and `ID2`, such that they always appear in the same order.

Swapping the IDs:

```py
s = df['ID1'] > df['ID2']
df.loc[s, ['ID1', 'ID2']] = df.loc[s, ['ID2', 'ID1']].values
print(df)
>>> ID1 Value ID2
0   a1  1   a2
1   a1  2   a2
2   a1  3   a2
3   a1  4   a2
4   a1  5   a2
5   b   6   None
6   c   7   None
```

Then we can do a simple groupby:

```py
df['RSUM'] = df.groupby(['ID1', 'ID2'], dropna=False)['Value'].transform("sum")
print(df)
>>> ID1 Value ID2 RSUM
0   a1  1   a2  15
1   a1  2   a2  15
2   a1  3   a2  15
3   a1  4   a2  15
4   a1  5   a2  15
5   b   6   None    6
6   c   7   None    7
```

Note the `dropna=False` to not discard IDs that have no pairing.
If you do not want to permanently swap the IDs, you can just create a temporary dataframe.